# Mysql increment value in one row each time it reads the same value in another row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, increment

Lets say i have a table called customer_order:

```
id|    cust#|    counter 
 1    1        1
 2    2        1 
 3    1        2 
 4    3        1
 5    2        2
 6    1        3
```

So the idea is, every time a customer (cust#) repeats, you want to increment counter as demonstrated above.I need to do this in the SELECT statement while quering data. I am using Pentaho kettle to query data from a database. How can i achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pure sql as:

```
update customer c
    set counter = (select count(*) from customer c2 where c2.cust# = c.cust# and c2.id <= c.id);
```

The above should be pretty efficient if you have an index on `customer(cust#, id)`.

You can also do this using variables, which might be more practical if you have more than a few tens of thousands of rows.

EDIT:

Buried deep down, I see the `I want to do this in a select`.  Oops.  Here is the `select` version:

```
select c.*,
       (select count(*) from customer c2 where c2.cust# = c.cust# and c2.id <= c.id) as counter
from customer c
```

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thanks for your quick response. I forgot to mention that cust# is not an original field in the table, that one that needs to be created in the select statement just to handle counter

Comment: @TheGeorgia . . . To quote:  "Lets say i have a table called customer_order" followed by three columns "id|    cust#|    counter ".  If you have a different question, create a new question with the relevant information.

Comment: @TheGeorgia To Quote " I forgot to mention that cust# is not an original field in the table, that one that needs to be created in the select statement just to handle counter " please mention this as comment under the question. Also if cust# is not original column how are you generating it ?